# Disavow file updating

Tags: seo, google, backlinks, disavow-links

i uploaded my disavow file about 2 weeks ago, by google webmaster-tools.

but now; i want to delete some urls from the list (updating disavow.txt)..

if i update my disavow .txt(delete old one, and upload updated one); will i continue to get positive ranking from that site, if the it really has positive rank?

or is it a irreversible/oneway step?

i read tons of article about link deleting; but couldnt be sure :/

Comment: thank you. i write all urls as domain status, and like domain:example.com (with no empty space)

Comment: WMT is always updating a new disavow file so why should they not consider changes? it would be illogical in my point of view

Answer (score 2):

I am a little confused by your question but here are some facts. You will not rank well or poorly. The disavow tells Google you do not have anything to do with a certain link. It helps to dodge getting a penalty.

1. Uploading a new file will wash out the old file. So, make sure you keep record of the old disavows and add them to the new file you will upload (with the new disavows).
2. This may help in a Penguin algo penalty case (I have seen that first hand) but IS NOT guaranteed to.
3. If the entire domain is spam, disavow the entire domain.
   # note goes here
   domain:example.com
4. If just on URL, only disavow the URL.
   # note goes here
   http://example.com/spammy-page/
5. Google suggests you try to remove the link first. Sometimes this is not possible.